# How to fetch data from multiple tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, fetch

[image]

For every project located in 'Stafford', list the project number, the controlling department number, and the department manager's last name, address, and birth date.

Comment: Don't post images like this. Create a fiddle instead or add it as a text in the post itself.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: Have you read the basic documentation on writing queries for SQL. Also, what is the query you tried before asking this question? Need to do your homework first. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Inner Join to Query from the different tables